# How to remove process from a job object on windows without terminating it

Tags: windows, object, jobs

Is there a way or API available through which I can remove the already assigned process from a job object and re-assign it to another job object?

Answer (score 1):

After a process is associated with a job, the association cannot be broken.
See here for more details: [Job Objects Creation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_jobs)

Comment: You should indicate that you're quoting from the linked article.